# R: Test for overlap of name values in dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, matching

I have a dataframe filled with names.

For a given row in the dataframe, I'd like to compare that row to every row above it in the df and determine if the number of matching names is less than or equal to 4 for every row.

**Toy Example where row 3 is the row of interest**

1. "Jim","Dwight","Michael","Andy","Stanley","Creed"
2. "Jim","Dwight","Angela","Pam","Ryan","Jan"
3. "Jim","Dwight","Angela","Pam","Creed","Ryan" <--- row of interest

So first we'd compare row 3 to row 1 and see that the name overlap is 3, which meets the <= 4 criteria.

Then we'd compare row 3 to row 2 and see that the name overlap is 5 which fails the <= 4 criteria, ultimately returning a failed condition for being <=4 for every row above it.

Right now I am doing this operation using a for loop but the speed is much too slow for the dataframe size I am working with.

Comment: You should post `dput( head(your_dataframe))` so we can figure out whether the values are factors or not. Then we can figure out whether the first step should be to convert to character before attempting to do a row-based count of intersecting values.

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(
  c("Jim","Dwight","Michael","Andy","Stanley","Creed"),
c("Jim","Dwight","Angela","Pam","Ryan","Jan"),
c("Jim","Dwight","Angela","Pam","Creed","Ryan")
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#    V1     V2      V3   V4      V5    V6
# 1 Jim Dwight Michael Andy Stanley Creed
# 2 Jim Dwight  Angela  Pam    Ryan   Jan
# 3 Jim Dwight  Angela  Pam   Creed  Ryan
```

Operation and output (sapply over columns with `%in%` and take `rowSums`)

```
out_lgl <- rowSums(sapply(df, '%in%', unlist(df[3,]))) <= 4

out_lgl
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
which(out_lgl)
# [1] 1
```

**Explanation:**

For each column, each element is compared to the third row (the vector `unlist(df[3,])`). The output is a matrix of logical values with the same dimensions as `df`, `TRUE` if there is a match.

```
sapply(df, '%in%', unlist(df[3,]))

#        V1   V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
# [1,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Then we can sum the `TRUE`s to see the number of matches for each row

```
rowSums(sapply(df, '%in%', unlist(df[3,])))
# [1] 3 5 6
```

**Edit:**

I have added the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option to the creation of `df` above. However, as far as I can tell the output of `%in%` is the same whether comparing factors with different levels or characters, so I don't believe this could change the results in any way. See example below

```
x <- c('b', 'c', 'z')
y <- c('a', 'b', 'g')

all.equal(x %in% y, factor(x) %in% factor(y))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: The light dawns and I reversed my downvote. I see that your results are not an accident (with your example) and I was misunderstanding how they came about. I also see that your method of creating the example resulted in all the values being in factor levels. I suspect that method may not succeed for the OP's dataset however.

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution as IceCreamToucan, but for any row.

For the data.frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(
  c("Jim","Dwight","Michael","Andy","Stanley","Creed"),
  c("Jim","Dwight","Angela","Pam","Ryan","Jan"),
  c("Jim","Dwight","Angela","Pam","Creed","Ryan")
)
```

For any row number i:

```
f <- function(i) {
  if(i == 1) return(T)
  r <- vapply(df[1:(i-1),], '%in%', unlist(df[i,]), FUN.VALUE = logical(i-1))
  out_lgl <- rowSums(as.matrix(r)) <= 4
  return(all(out_lgl))
}
```